# Узнать партнерскую сеть канала на Youtube

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Добрый день, необходимо узнать к какой партнёрской программе (медиасети) подключён определённый канал на Youtube.

Безрезультатно перепробовал много методов API. Подскажите необходимый метод.

Comment: спросить у собственника канала?

Comment: @KoVadim узнать партнёрскую программу нужно более чем для 100 тыс. каналов, поэтому ваш вариант не жизнеспособен.

Comment: похожий вопрос: [How to programmatically find out what channels are part of a given YouTube network?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12570034/4279)